# T-SQL how to create a table whose structure is in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I create a stored procedure to create a table, whose structure is stored in another table, with t-sql of course and sql server?

Comment: What is stored in another table? Structure like information_schema.columns or you would like to duplicate table structure? To duplicate structure use `select top 0 * into newtable from...`.

Comment: yeah columns ,colums that are going to be used to fill the new table !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

T-SQL allows to create tables on the fly using `SELECT * ... INTO` syntax:

```
SELECT * INTO TargetTable
FROM SourceTable
-- any false returning condition will do
WHERE 1 = 0
```

This can also be written elegantly (thanks to `Deadsheep39`):

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO TargetTable
FROM SourceTable
```

However, this will fail if TargetTable already exists, so you should check for its existence:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TheSchema.TargetTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TargetTable
```

Also, no indexes, constraints or trigger will be created. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more details.

If you want to go dynamic (table names are parameters) you can create and execute a dynamic query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateTable
(
    @SourceTable VARCHAR(128),
    @TargetTable VARCHAR(128)
)    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
        SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetTable) + '
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceTable) + '
        -- any false returning condition will do
        WHERE 1 = 0'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
GO
```

Comment: Check if exists can be simplified with system function **object_id** - `if object_id('dbname.schema.tablename') is not null drop table dbname.schema.tablename` or if you are on your db with default schema only `if object_id('tablename') is not null drop table tablename` or example on tempdb `if object_id('tempdb..#tablename') is not null drop table tempdb..#tablename`.

Comment: @Deadsheep39 - I have simplified object existence check as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct query as string with `CREATE TABLE` statement and execute it by using `sp_executesql` stored procedure.

For instance in this way:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE TABLE Table(Col nvarchar(50) NULL)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

where in the `@query` variable you can build based on what kind of table you need.

Comment: So basically you can execute a create table statement in a more difficult way than necessary, with input that you have to manually define? Not a good answer to the OP, -1.

Comment: As far as I understood the question was how to create a table dynamically the structure of it is stored in another table.

Comment: Yes, you can use SELECT INTO but in the question what kind of new table structure  was not specified. Only later in a comment "yeah columns ,colums that are going to be used to fill the new table"

Comment: I see that the accepted answer doesn't necessarily answer the question as I understand it, but still, your answer doesn't really contain much besides the syntax for `CREATE TABLE`. As per the comment it is made clear that the OP wants to create a table based on the structure of another table, and thus your answer doesn't provide much..

Comment: But from the date of the answer I see that it's not all bad.. If you make some small edit to ur answer I'll remove my downvote (can't do it now..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133541/discussion-between-vasyl-zvarydchuk-and-tobb).

Comment: Anything really (just add a letter or something), SO wont let me change my vote unless there is an edit.. I could edit it myself, nvm.